# The length of an item of an array should be undefined however in debugger it has a value

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, for-loop

Here is a solution to subdivide an array into smaller chunks.  The solution uses a length property on an array item, which does not make sense to me as it should be undefined; however, the solution does indeed work, and when I run it as a snippet in chrome dev tools with a debugger it indeed shows a value, I am just not sure how it works.  I cannot explain why `last.length` has any value at all.  Can someone explain why this works, and why I can't console.log a value for it?

```
const chunk = (arr, size) => {
    let newArr = []
    for (let el of arr) {
        let last = newArr[newArr.length -1]
        console.log(last, 'i am last')
        if(!last || last.length === size) {
            newArr.push([el])
        } else {
            last.push(el)
        }
    } 
    return newArr
}

// chunk([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2) --> [[ 1, 2], [3, 4], [5]]
```

Comment: Cause `last` is an array (as the items in an array of arrays are arrays) ? Arrays have a `.length` ?

Comment: I think he's referring to the fact that `let last = newArr[newArr.length -1]` would result in `undefined` being assigned to last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: When `last` is undefined, this expression

```
(!last || last.length === size)
```

still evaluates to true.  Read on for more details.

On the first iteration of the loop, this assignment occurs:

```
let last = newArr[-1];
```

Thus, last is assigned `undefined` as a value.

The subsequent statement:

```
if(!last || last.length === size) {
```

`!last` evaluates to true, because that's literally what `!undefined` evaluates to.

As a result of `!last` being true, `last.length` is not evaluated at all.  Hence, no exception is raised because there's not actual attempt to evaluate what's essentially `undefined.length` This is a feature of most popular programming languages known as **boolean short circuiting**.  Once the first part of an OR expression evaluates to true, anything to the right of it is not evaluated.  The same principal applies to AND statements when the left expression evaluates to false.

That triggers the next line:

```
newArr.push([el])
```

Which gives give the array a valid element.  Thus `newArr.size` is now 1.

On subsequent iterations of the loop, last is correctly assigned the last element in `newArr`.

Answer (score 1):

You could move the declaration of `last` outside of the loop and prevent for every item a new access to `newArr`.

```js
const chunk = (arr, size) => {
    let newArr = [];
    let last;
    for (let el of arr) {
        if (!last || last.length === size) {
            last = [];
            newArr.push(last);
        }
        last.push(el);
    } 
    return newArr
}

console.log(chunk([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2));
```

Answer (score 1):

A variation of Nina Scholz's suggestion, just with getting rid of the `undefined`-magic completely:

```js
const chunk = (arr, size) => {
    let last = [];
    let newArr = [last];
    for (let el of arr) {
        if (last.length === size) {
            last = [];
            newArr.push(last);
        }
        last.push(el);
    } 
    return newArr
}

console.log(chunk([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2));
```